# Video don't play in Firefox (but play in Chrome)

Tags: html, firefox, video, html5-video

I try to add the `video` tag on a website, but I encounter a problem.
The video is well played in Chrome but not in Firefox even the URL is correct.

```
<video src="http://127.0.0.1/st_martin/index.php/fre/content/download/89/643/file/test-video.mp4" width="640" height="266" poster="/st_martin/var/ezwebin_site/storage/images/les-partenaires/l-auberge-gourmande/video-1/764-5-fre-FR/Video-1_large.png" controls>  
    Your browser does not support the <code>video</code> element.  
</video>
```

And enervous thing : when I copy/paste file URL in firefox it plays the video without any problem.

Using embed video player cause a neverending loading animation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firefox does not support .[mp4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_video#Supported_video_formats) playback. Try conveting the video to .ogg format which is fast becoming a standard format for html 5 applications.

Comment: Yeap, no support for MPEG-4 and H.264 in Firefox yet. It can be easily checked with http://html5test.com/ (jump to video section)